# Is there any RFC or BAPI implementing the transaction rsscd001 for displaying change documents in SAP?

Tags: saprfc, sap-basis, jco, bapi

I would like to know whether there is any RFC or BAPI functions to display change documents (transaction `RSSCD001`) based on input query in SAP. The customer requirement is to implement a java monitor system on SAP without adding any ABAP functions on the SAP server.

I tried to make use of 'RFC_READ_TABLE' functions, which is deprecated according to the official documents,  to read the CDPOS and CDHDR table and join them. But as vwegert said, to traverse the table CDPOS is really time-costing, as it contains billions of table entries.

My intention of this query is to find changes to all bank details of vendors.

Any other thoughts?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least resource-consuming way to do this would be to use the workflow runtime system to actively notify the java application whenever a change document is written. You don't have to write any ABAP functions to do this, just setup the workflow engine (using the [automatic customizing](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_di471/helpdata/en/a0/28e937a5caba6ee10000009b38f842/frameset.htm)) and customize the event generation ([documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_di471/helpdata/en/c5/e4aeef453d11d189430000e829fbbd/frameset.htm)). Then, you write a java service that connects to the SAP system using JCo and [registers as an RFC server](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/09/c88442a07b0e53e10000000a155106/frameset.htm) using a destination of Type TCP/IP and a registered program ID. This java server program has to [provide a function module handler](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/20/b65a4201301453e10000000a155106/frameset.htm) that can be called [using tRFC](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/53/b65a4201301453e10000000a155106/frameset.htm) from the SAP system. Finally, add [a linkage entry](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_di471/helpdata/en/c5/e4b027453d11d189430000e829fbbd/frameset.htm) that will tell the workflow runtime system to call your java program each time a change document is written.

Of course, this will only record the changes that happen after installation, not the historical changes.

Answer (score 0):

warning : I'm not very familliar with this field.

The RFC function BAPI_VENDOR_FIND (BAPI Vendor) seems to be used to find vendor based on values in table. You could use it to check gainst the modification date. This is not perfect, as there is no relationnal operator, only equals, and you'll have to check against several dates...

hopes this helps
Guillaume